# Poltergeist and Capybara can't open page by its url, returns about_blank

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I am using Capybara 1.1.4 with poltergeist as PhantomJS driver. When I run this code on ruby:

```
visit('some_url')
```

I get 'about_blank'. It happens when I open specific dev environment. With other sites' urls it works great. Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: what is the exact url that you are trying to visit. is it really `some_url`?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'some_url' in other domain? If yes, Capybara (and Cucumber) have several limitations to test other domains, even subdomains. I mean, it will not work without workarounds.

Comment: It's the same domain. It works fine on Selenium, when I run tests on browsers.